# How to use the merge function with excel files?

Tags: r, merge

So I have an excel file that contains a long list of ID numbers and batch numbers. I also have 3 other excel files that contain ID numbers that I need to find batch numbers for. Basically, my boss wants me to merge all 4 excel files together in R using the merge function in order to find the batch numbers for the 3 excel files that are missing batch numbers. I've never used the merge function before and I have no idea where to start.

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/two-table.html Also, please do not use the rstudio tag for R questions.

Comment: I'm using RStudio Phil. Accidently left it out of the original post; my bad.

Comment: RStudio is just an IDE, and it has nothing to do with your question. Tagging it makes as much sense as tagging your computer's operating system, or the desk it's sitting on.

Comment: I'm sure you're familiar with Stack overflow and their practice of making you add tags to your question. Should I have chosen another word that made you more comfortable Phil?

Comment: Use the R tag for R questions. This is for your own benefit if you actually want your questions answered.

Comment: I've had all my questions answered so far with the RStudio tag. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: Firstly, they weren't all answered. One can see your past questions by looking at your profile. Secondly, they were answered after the tags were edited according to the topic of your questions. Thirdly, I don't understand why you are fighting me when I'm trying to help you.

Comment: Phil your link did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Import excel files into the data frame `read_excel`
2. Use the `left_join` function

See the example below

```
library(tidyverse)
dfExel1 = tibble(
  ID = 1:10000,
  batch = ID*2
)

dfExcel2 = tibble(
  ID = sample(1:10000, 10)
)

dfExcel2 %>% left_join(dfExel1, "ID")
```